# Comprehensive list of punishments for all 365 negative commandments

Tags: mitzvah, reward-punishment, negative-commandments

Is there a comprehensive list of all the punishments for the 365 negative commandments?

The **Rambam** in Hilchos Sanhedrin reveals 243 (see below)--
what are the punishments for transgressing the other 122 negative commandments and where can this  be found?

- **36** [capital punishment] - people killed by Beis Din ([Hilchos Sanhedrin 15:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_The_Sanhedrin_and_the_Penalties_within_their_Jurisdiction.15.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
- **21** [*kareit*] - negative commandments that are punishable by kerait, but which are not punishable by execution by the court, for which lashes are administered ([Hilchos Sanhedrin 19:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_The_Sanhedrin_and_the_Penalties_within_their_Jurisdiction.19.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
- **18** [*misas b'dei shamayim*] negative commandments that are punishable by death by the hand of heaven, whose transgression involve a deed, for which lashes are administered ([Hilchos Sanhedrin 19:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_The_Sanhedrin_and_the_Penalties_within_their_Jurisdiction.19.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
- **168** [lashes] - negative commandments who are neither punishable by kerait, nor by execution by the court, for which lashes are administered.([Hilchos Sanhedrin 19:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_The_Sanhedrin_and_the_Penalties_within_their_Jurisdiction.19.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

Comment: maybe shaarey teshuvah shaar 3

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Thanks! Will take a look when I get the chance (in the meantime posting the link here https://www.sefaria.org/Shaarei_Teshuvah.3?lang=bi)

Comment: @AlBerko a good point- such a list would hopefully note that as well

Answer (score 4):

1. When you say "no punishment" you meant not justiciable by humans. We have no doubt all transgressions are liable by Heavenly court.
2. There are different sorts of negative Mitzvot that bear no such punishment (here's the list of [all Negative Mitzvos](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%A4%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9D#%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9C%D7%90_%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94)):

   - Negative Mitzvos that are Lav haNitak Le'Ese (Makos 15a) - a negative Mitzvah that has a related positive one to fix it. As a person can fix his misdeed by performing a linked positive Mitzvah there's no immediate punishment. For example, all money related misdeeds bear no punishment because the transgressor can pay back See additional examples [here](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%95_%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%A7_%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94#%D7%93%D7%95%D7%92%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA).
   - Negative Thoughts that count as transgressions are also not punishable (probably because we can't have two witnesses), for example, imaging existing of other deities. Or Mitvos of "following one's eyes and heart".
   - Negative Feelings (equals thought?) like not to love transgressors or #50 on the list or #58 - "Not to be afraid of enemies".
   - Negative offensive sayings are also not punishable AFAIK (like offending a widow or an orphan) .
   - Overriding a negative Mitzvah by Shev veAl Ta'ase (not taking actions): for example, failing to help one's fellow (Mitzvah לא תעמוד על דם רעך) by NOT acting is not punishable.
   - Various long lasting Mitzvos, like #46 - Not to dwell in Egypt.
   - Some Negative Mitzvos are too vague to judge, there's no specific defined action, for example, #64 Not to try G-d in His ways - there's no particular action linked to that Mitzvah.
   - IIRC, prohibitions of "Not to become impure by ..." (לא לטמא) are also not punishable retroactively.

Comment: Perhaps translate most of your halachic terms for the uninitiated

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what was written above, Me'am Loez parshas mishpatim lists the ones liable for Excommunication/Herem:

Blasphemy, contempt of Jewish court, calling another a derogatory name, disrespecting torah or rabbinic law or anything pertaining thereto, ignoring a hazmana (beis din summon), refusing to follow a verdict of a beis din, keeping a vicious dog on ones property, refusing to repair a bad ladder, selling non-jews property that result in other jews getting grief and not taking responsibility for it, committing perjury in a non-jewish court that causes property loss, a cohen that slaughters and doesn't give the portion to another priest, violating yom tov shenii hagalus, doing work after noon on erev pesach, causing people to eat korbonot outside the beis hamikdash, causing public to do a chilul hashem, making calendar calculations to make the calendar outside eretz yisrael, lifnei ever, preventing a person from doing a good deed (including discouraging a rav to give a torah lesson), selling treif slaughtered meat to a jew, willfully causing an erection--do not follow your heart or eyes.., divorcing a wife then continuing to have business dealings, unlawfully excommunicating another, allowing a women to marry someone forbidden to her, not helping to bury the dead where there is no chevrat kadisha, bringing a case to non-jewish court, rendering psakiem in the same city as one's rav without his permission, insulting a talmid chocham, opening and reading another person's mail, giving jewish money to non-jews (without permission), intermarrying with karaites, dishonoring groups set up to do good (e.g. tzedakah organizations)

Comment: Good point but these aren't all negative commandments. (Rambam also brings it https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%95_%D7%99%D7%93)